# How to extract a String before comma in Java

Tags: java, regex

I  have a String which  looks like  "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00".Now my requirement is i want to extract the String before comma and want to put them in a list and another list in another list ,I have done something but that is not working ,I am giving my code

```
String[] toks = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00".
                split("\\s*,\\s*|(?<=[ap]m)(?=\\d)");

for (String tok: toks){
        System.out.printf("[%s]%n", tok);
    }
```

But that  is giving output as

```
[12:00:00]
[2:30:003:45:00]
[23:45:00]
```

My desired result is  12:00:00,3:45:00 in a list and 2:30:00,23:45:00 in a list ,how to achieve that??somebody please help

Comment: can anyone help i am not getting what to do ??

Comment: Your question description is very unclear. Maybe try to explain what are you trying to do, how many list you want to create, which part of text should be placed in which list and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do matching and extract these elements in 2 different lists:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
             "(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})");

Matcher m = p.matcher( "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00" );

List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); 

while (m.find()) {
    list1.add(m.group(1));
    list2.add(m.group(2));
}

System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", list1, list2);
```

**Output:**

```
[12:00:00, 3:45:00]
[2:30:00, 23:45:00]
```

There are 2 capturing groups being used here to extract data in 2 different lists:

```
(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})  # hh:mm:ss timestamp (group #1)
\\s*,\\s*                     # separator is a comma surrounded by optional spaces
(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})  # hh:mm:ss timestamp (group #2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
final String s = "12:00:00, 2:30:003:45:00,23:45:00";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
final List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
  tokens.add(m.group(1));
}
for (String tok: tokens){
  System.out.printf("[%s]%n", tok);
}
```

Comment: its doing but my requriment was to put them into a seperate list

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you achieve what you want for this case in particular (where input is your string):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s*,\\s*(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.matches) {
   list1.add(m.group(1));
   list1.add(m.group(3));
   list2.add(m.group(2));
   list2.add(m.group(4));
}
```

This code makes the assumption that those are 4 times, the second and the third have no separator and that the seconds part is always present and has two digits.

For more info on what that pattern means, check [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

However, you should consider using a more useful string if possible as input. If you can control the output, consider placing a space or any other separator between the two sets and create a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like `/.\d:.\d:.\d/` to match with a time pattern?